# Google Page Speed - CSS Above The Fold - Bootstrap Template Plugin

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-pagespeed

Google PageSpeed Insights is showing me that I should place my CSS below the fold.

However, I'm using Bootstrap as a templating plugin.

Now, I could print bootstrap.min.css inline on my homepage but I really don't want to do that because it's inefficient for the overall site experience.

I could also use async or defer modifiers, but bootstrap is essential for the loading of the page template and it would load in a corrupted way before sorting itself out.

It makes more sense to load a CSS file one time, and cache it on the user's browser so that they don't have to load a large plugins every time they visit a page.

Seems like a real conflict of interest here:

Google wants an initial page to load as fast as possible....but it's bad practice for a sustained site session to inline style information.

Is there any solution to this problem that will still allow my bootstrap site to load normally and at the same time allow me to get the pagespeed score improvement?

Comment: Google Page Speed is drunk.

Comment: @Aziz I have to agree!! Many SEO's are inlining hundreds of lines of CSS just to get 100 pagespeed. They need to reconsider this.....

Answer (score 2):

Try this and see if the google page speed improves:

```
<script>
var cb = function() {
var l = document.createElement('link'); l.rel = 'stylesheet';
l.href = 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css';
var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; h.parentNode.insertBefore(l, h);
};
var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
if (raf) raf(cb);
else window.addEventListener('load', cb);
</script>
```

Comment: Am I correct in saying this basically hides the css request from the google bot? An interesting approach :)

Comment: Adding a `<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"/></noscript>` at the end of the script could be beneficial...